# Windows 8.1 Update stuck on Checking for updates in 2017

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

At the start of 2017 all Windows 8.1 x64 computers I knew of were stuck on Checking for updates with 100% CPU usage by the Windows Update service(svchost.exe -k netsvcs).

No workarounds and troubleshooters on the internet help. Even a clean Windows 8.1 x64 on the VirtualBox gets stuck.

**Edit**: This is not a duplicate of another question asked Oct 5 '16. Because the answer there is suggesting to install KB3102812 update. This update was already installed on my system. The solution for a current(2017) problem is to install a different update.